# Forgetting mathematics. Memory problem

Tags: soft-question

I got an A from Game Theory. But after that i forgot almost all the formulas and theorems. What should i do to prevent that? Do you forget math like i do?

Comment: That might be a symptom of cramming for an exam, rather than really understanding the material.

Comment: I do forget even though the math I am studying is self-studying and not for exams or grades. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: +1 Because I'd like to see possible learning habbits being suggested

Comment: unfortunately that is true. But our education system made us like this. (I live in Turkey)

Comment: I have forgotten what the question is... No matter how many times I learn $\sin,\cos$ product sum formulae, I never remember and always end up re-deriving.

Comment: I think its OK to forget formulas and theorems provided that you don't forget the main ideas. For example in certain theorems there is one or two important idea that once you remember you will be able to reconstruct the proof again

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748197/a-good-way-to-retain-mathematical-understanding/748268#748268

Comment: Have you done any game theory since - does it interest and excite you - have you sought applications and references?

Answer (score 8):

I would take heart and persevere. Something I have learned over the years is this:

Although it may *feel* like the material you learned is all gone, it is actually hidden in your brain somewhere. You will find that if you go back to the books and try to re-learn Game Theory it will be much easier than it was the first time - you will keep feeling that "oh yeah..." as the light bulbs go off and everything starts to return.

It feels like I have learned some things a hundred times over, but you just have to accept that. Not all of us, unfortunately, have memories like Euler did :(

And yes, as the accepted answer to PandaBear's link in the comments says, teaching is by far the best way to remember things. Take time to slowly and thoroughly explain something to a student and you will find that it won't easily go away.